# can I run readonly git slaves behind a loadbalancer?

Tags: git, cluster-computing, load-balancing

My servers are querying git very often.  I figure multiple read slaves will help.

Can you place git servers behind a load balancer?
On the git/ssh protocol supported.

Comment: why does it have to be git/ssh? just use https and you are good to go!